# How can I add two icons to button

Tags: qooxdoo

I want to create a button with two icons. One at the left edge and at the right edge.
How can I do it?

example:
https://archive.qooxdoo.org/current/playground/#Hello%20World-ria

Comment: it seems I need to use _createChildControlImpl with new element smt like 
case "newIcon":
control = new qx.ui.basic.Image(this.newIcon());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to redefine `_createChildControlImpl` method and create the second icon there:

```
qx.Class.define("myapp.Button", {
    extend : qx.ui.form.Button,

    construct(name, path){
        this.base(arguments, name, path);
        this._createChildControl("secondicon");
    },

    members: {
        _createChildControlImpl(id, hash){
            let control;
            switch(id) {
                case "secondicon":
                    control = new qx.ui.basic.Image(this.getIcon());
                    this._add(control);
                    break;
            }
            return control || super._createChildControlImpl(id);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can take advantage of the fact that every widget is in essence a container. You can call the button's `_add` method, as shown here:

```
var button1 = 
  new qx.ui.form.Button("First Button", "icon/22/apps/internet-web-browser.png");

// Add another icon. It'll be added after whatever has already been
// added to the button, which is the original icon and the button text.
button1._add(new qx.ui.basic.Image("icon/22/apps/internet-web-browser.png"));
```

Comment: This solution is shortest but I am not sure to call protected methods from object outside of class is good idea.